# How to design correct data model for related tables using sql joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, data-analysis

I have a Organization table with relationship as 'One Org' will have 'multiple Suborg' and 'exactly 2 supervisors'. The Supervisors RoleID is mapped to Roles Table 'ID' along with other roles.

```
Organization table: ID, OrgName, OrganizationTypeID,OrgModifiedDate
OrganizationType  : ID, TypeName
SubOrg Table      : ID, OrgID, SubOrgName, SuborgModifiedDate
Users Table       : Id, RoleID , RoleName, OrgID, SubOrgID, UserModifiedDate
```

The relationship is One Organization can have multiple organization and the number of Supervisor in every Organization are 2.

When I am joining the above table with the below query, it gives me multiple rows of repeating data.

```
 select distinct
    o.id OrgID,
    o.name as OrgName,
    ot.Name as orgTypeName,
    isnull (o.ModifiedOn, o.Createdon) as Org_ModifiedDate,
    s.id SubOrgID,
    s.name as suborgName,
    isnull(s.ModifiedOn,s.CreatedOn) as SubOrg_ModifiedDate,
    u.Name SupervisorName,
    u.RoleID SupervisorID,
    u.id UserID
from users u left join Organizations o on U.OrgID = o.id
         left join Suborganizations s on s.orgID = o.Id
         left join OrganizationTypes ot on o.OrganizationTypeid = ot.id
    where U.RoleID = '9774904F-E74E-4F59-9552-FB3DC233D25B'
```

How do I achieve in my PowerBI model where I have to show data in a table like the picture below,

Comment: You don't tell us how the desired output is a function of the input, so why do you expect us to be able to tell you what a correct query is? You don't give us the input corrsponding to desired output, so why do you expect us to be able to guess what that function is? (Also you left out your "picture". But don't give a picture, give text.) Please give a [mre]. PS Although FKs are commonly (wrongly) called "relationships", they are (cardinality) constraints. Tables (base & query results) represent relation(ship)s/associations. We don't need to know constraints to query.

Comment: @philipxy correct mate..but dont be harsh on OP as OP is a newbie

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja I don't think that comment is harsh. What do you think is harsh about it? I think those semi-rhetorical questions are important ones for the asker to ask themself & answer for themself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should only break the tables into more when its required. As in above I dont think so, if it does contribute to any good with normalizing suborgs to suborgs table and other etc. Rather have only 2 tables

```
     Organization and Users
```

Organization table:

```
     ID, TypeName,OrgName 
     SubOrgName, OrgModifiedDate 
     , SuborgModifiedDate
```

Users Table:

```
    Id, RoleID , RoleName, OrgID, 
     UserModifiedDate
```

Query

```
    Select column1, column2.... From 
    users u left join Organizations o on
    u.Id=o.Id where where U.RoleID = 
     '9774904F-E74E-4F59-9552- 
      FB3DC233D25B'
```